# Bind Two Properties to DataGridTemplateColumn TextBox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, mvvm

I want to bind two properties to my DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a TextBox.

I have a column called HST. In that column I want users to enter a formula and when focus is left, or the column is no longer in edit state, the value is displayed, similar behavior with MS excel.

I have two properties where I have the formula stored as well as where I have the value from the formula stored.

```
 public String SubTotal
    {
        get
        {
            String[] l_ComputeArr = l_HST.Split('=');
            if (l_ComputeArr.Length > 1)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    var v = dt.Compute(l_ComputeArr[1], "");
                    l_SubTotal = v.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }
            return l_SubTotal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (l_SubTotal != value)
            {
                l_SubTotal = value;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
        }
    }
    public String HST
    {
        get { return l_HST; }
        set
        {
            if (l_HST != value)
            {
                l_HST = value;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("HST");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
        }
    }
```

Subtotal has the value and HST has the formula

I want to make HST hidden and have similar behavior with MS Excel, where the formula is displayed when Subtotal is being edited and the value is displayed after the edit is complete

[image]

I have a class called observable object that my viewmodels Inherit from.

This class has a method RaisePropertyChanged, which updates the View Elements.

```
 public abstract class ObservableObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [field: NonSerialized]
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
              handler(this, e);
          }
      }

      protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
      {
         var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
         this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
      }

      protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
       {
           VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Warns the developer if this Object does not have a public property with
       /// the specified name. This method does not exist in a Release build.
       /// </summary>
       [Conditional("DEBUG")]
       [DebuggerStepThrough]
       public void VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName)
       {
           // verify that the property name matches a real,  
           // public, instance property on this Object.
           if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
          {
               Debug.Fail("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
           }
       }
   }
```

My question:

I want to have similar ms excel behavior on my datagrid.

By that I mean, I do not want to have a separate column displaying the formula from the column displaying the evaluation of the expression/formula

In ms excel a column displays the expression/formula when in edit state, and displays the value of that expression when in view state.

Comment: Where is your code for the PropChange events?

Comment: I have a custom code for that. A child of inotifypropertychanged. Its called RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: What question are you asking? I don't see a question in this post. I assume the problem is you aren't getting the MS Excel behavior, but that isn't stated explicitly. Moreover, without that custom code, we have no idea what you're trying and thus have no idea what the problem is. Please include the code for the raised events.

Comment: @JacobBarnes I have edited my question and included the code. And made my question more clear and explicit. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- 
        Template used when cell is in editing state. 
        HST appears to be your formula. 
        -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding HST}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

        <!-- 
        Template used when cell is not in editing state. 
        -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtotal}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```